# Filtering nested list inside nest lists

Tags: javascript, angular, filtering

I am looking for advice how to do optimally below issue. I use angular 8.
so i have menuItems i want to filter , each item is expandable , has sub items, items can have sub items as well and this can go on.
if i search item name i am updating menuItems in sidebar, how can i deep dive till sub array and return them or how can achieve to return full list that matches the condition and return parent &child structure?
i can filter in any sub level manually like this.

```
return element.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(userInput.toUpperCase())!==-1
```

instead of iterating arrays sub items that if sub array exists, then filter , is there better way recursively to that ?

Comment: Could you give a sample of the input? Yes, recursion would be the better way.

Comment: Hi sure. for example. if i filter by test i  have to get all tests, both in sub list and in first dimension array, . Also inside of sub list each object also can have sub array again. it s accordion example 

let arr = [
  {
    name:'Favour',
    sub:[
      {name:'Test'},
      {name:'Test 4'},
      {name:'Test 5'},{name:'Kerim'}
    ]},
  {name:'Test55',sub:[{name:'Test 1'},{name:'Test 11'},{name:'Test 22'},{name:'Kerim'}]}

]